# Distribution of Rational Numbers on $[0,1]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graphing-functions

If I define the function

$$\Phi(n) := \sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k),$$

where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function,

and I define $Q_n(x)$ to be the number of distinct rational numbers with demoninators $\leq n$ and values $\in (0,x]$,

and I define

$$F(x) := \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{Q_n(x)}{\Phi(n)}$$
on $[0,1]$,

and I finally define $f(x) = F'(x)$.

Does $F(x)$ exist? If so, is it differentiable? If so, what does $f(x)$ look like?

My intuition says that $F$ should be the identity function. Is this true?

Comment: Why does $F(x)$ exist? Why is it differentiable? Your definition of $\Phi(n)$ is missing some good indexation, too. The sum has $k$, $n$ and $x$. Can you fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I really need to check these things. I meant $\leq x$

Comment: And "below" means?

Comment: $\leq n$, although since I use a limit to infinity I don't think it should matter...

Comment: We know that $\Phi(n)\sim \frac{3n^2}{\pi^2}$, not sure what the error term is, however.

Comment: Presumably, you mean "distinct positive rationals." Or maybe non-negative.

Comment: OK. Fixed. I think I mean positive such that $Q_n(1) = \Phi(n)\;\forall n$

Comment: Certainly, $Q_n(m)=m\Phi(n)$ for all natural numbers $m,n$, so $F(x)=x$ exists for natural numbers $x$.

Comment: I think you can likely prove it by first proving for rational $x$, which might be a little easier.

Comment: It's definitely not set theory. It's number theory.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Well, I'm kind of new to number theory of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $F(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Sketch of proof: $\Phi(n)$ counts all primitive lattice points in the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,n)$, and $(n,n)$. (Here a lattice point $(a,b)$ is primitive if $\gcd(a,b)=1$. The bijection sends $(a,b)$ to $a/b$.)

You can count primitive lattice points by inclusion-exclusion: if $F(n)$ is the total number of lattice points in the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,n)$, and $(n,n)$, then $\Phi(n) = \sum_{d=1}^\infty \mu(d)F(n/d)$.

Similarly, $Q_n(x)$ counts all primitive lattice points in the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,n)$, and $(xn,n)$. And thus $Q_n(x)$ can also be calculated using inclusion-exclusion, in terms of the total number of lattice points in scaled versions of this triangle.

Finally, the number of lattice points in a large triangle is basically the same as its area.

Comment: This seems that it should work, but you keep switching back between "primitive lattice points" and "lattice points". And inclusion-exclusion results in a ratio of sums. I was wondering if you could add to your proof with a little more mathematics? 
Thanks

Comment: @k_g, I don't know how to add more mathematics to this answer, but I think I can remove some: I think the inclusion-exclusion stuff is unnecessary. Greg Martin, please let me know if what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: Here's Greg Martin's argument boiled down. For convenience, let's change the definition of $Q_n$ to use the interval $(0, x)$ instead of $(0, x]$. This only changes $Q_n(x)$ by one or less, so it doesn't affect the definition of $F(x)$. Now, observe that $\Phi(n) = Q_n(1)$. Moreover, $Q_n(x)$ is the number of lattice points in the right triangle under $(xn, n)$. The number of lattice points in a triangle becomes proportional to its area as the triangle grows. [*Continued...*]

Comment: [... *continued*] Thus, as $n$ grows, the ratio $Q_n(x)/Q_n(1)$ approaches the ratio of the areas of the right triangles under $(xn, n)$ and $(n, n)$, which is $x$.